# How to interrupt the MS Identity Authentication Pipeline to check if user is in DB and if not deny authentication

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I use MS active directory for my authentication and MS Graph for my web app, however I have a DB which only contains select Users from our organizations Active Directory in Azure. I do not have the ability to control the active directory permissions and policies for my app so I want to rely on my DB for that. So I use an event in the login process to check what the Users ID in my DB is based on the email address provided in the claims info of the AD token provided from their login and I store this User ID for later use in my API rather than relying on storing in the front end which could be manipulated. However, if no results of this DB check are returned (ie, that email is not in my db) I want to revoke the access token and redirect the user to you do not have permission for my web app or something similar. Is that even possible or has the cookie/token already been issued to give the user full access to my app? Maybe there is a different event I should use for querying my DB first for this check? My code in my program.cs is as follows:

```
//authentication pipeline
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        //Tap into this event to add a UserID Claim to a new HttpContext identity
                        OnTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            //This query returns the UserID from the DB by sending the email address in the claim from Azure AD
                            string query = "select dbo.A2F_0013_ReturnUserIDForEmail(@Email) as UserID";
                            string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DBContext");
                            string signInEmailAddress = context.Principal.FindFirstValue("preferred_username");

                            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                            {
                                var queryResult = connection.QueryFirst(query, new { Email = signInEmailAddress });

                                var claims = new List<Claim>
                                {
                                    new Claim("UserID", queryResult.UserID.ToString())
                                };

                                var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                                context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                        //The SPA does not know when user session expires so this returns a 401 error for front end to use rather than a 302 redirect to MS login which axios cannot handle
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                        {
                            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account") || context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Base") || context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Dashboard"))
                            {
                                if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                                {
                                    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                                    context.Response.Headers.Add("ExpiredTokenRedirectUri", builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ExpiredTokenRedirectUri"));
                                }

                                context.HandleResponse();
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;

                        }
                    };
                }).EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Comment: we can get the user identity in `OnTokenValidated` event and write your logic. `OnTokenValidated = context =>{ var iden = context.Principal.Identity;`

Comment: My issue is if the result is not found what should my code do to stop the token from being issued? And isnt the OnTokenValidated isnt that event too late or should i use. a earlier one?

Comment: I'm not sure and I compared [all the events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-3.1#properties) and think `OnTokenValidated` maybe a good option because I can get user identity in this event, then we can use this identity to query in the database...

Comment: So if the identity is not in the db what would I add to my code to cancel the log in? Thanks.

Comment: And as you can see above I do use that event already so I can just add to that. I just don’t know what to add to cancel it all out.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, really busy these days. In my humble opinion, the whole process should be, APP redirect to AAD, then AAD sign in and if sign in successfully it can give a user indentity response, or it will give failure information in AAD page. When a successful information come back to APP, maybe it will trigger event for example OnTokenValidated, then we can try to add custom authentication rules into it. what we can found in SO are more likely adding custom claims, for custom auth rule, I haven't test it out, but I trust we have to delete the authorized identity information.